# React Native Android: Request works in android emulator, but not Play Store build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, http, nginx

I have a React Native app that is making a simple sign in request. This request works in the ios simulator and works when I install the build onto my device. It does not work when I download the app from the Play Store.

I have tried the following: I have re-installed and installed the app. 
Looked at production logs, I don't see any record that the request reaches the rails server. I have been using bugsnag logging.

Here is the request:

```
sendLoginEmail = (isResend) => {
    bugsnag.notify(new Error(`1: ${this.state.email}`))
    enterEmail(this.state.email).then(response => {
      console.log("sle response!")
      console.log(response)
      bugsnag.notify(new Error(`2: ${this.state.email}`))
      bugsnag.notify(new Error(JSON.stringify(response)))
      if (response.status === 200) {
        this.setState({isEmail: false, isLoading: false, warningMessage: isResend ? "Email resent" : null});
      } else {
        this.setState({isLoading: false, warningMessage: "Something went wrong. Please try again."})
      }
    }).catch(response => {
      bugsnag.notify(new Error(JSON.stringify(response)))
    })
  }
```

`enterEmail` looks like this:

```
export const enterEmail = (email) => {
  return fetch(`${host}/v2/users`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      user: {
        email
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Bugsnag logs the first error (`bugsnag.notify(new Error(`1: ${this.state.email}`))`) and catches the thrown error and logs the response. The response shows the following line in index.android.bundle: `new TypeError('Network request failed')`.

Here are my nginx.error.logs:

```
2019/08/23 09:57:46 [info] 885#885: *246 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 124.251.44.162, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2019/08/23 10:01:44 [info] 885#885: *265 client 208.94.74.81 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 11:15:43 [info] 885#885: *267 client 103.208.200.14 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 14:03:38 [info] 885#885: *269 client 151.217.75.156 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 15:01:17 [info] 885#885: *271 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 71.82.97.158, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2019/08/23 15:01:17 [info] 885#885: *272 client 71.82.97.158 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 17:18:01 [info] 885#885: *274 client 186.154.93.81 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 19:36:42 [info] 885#885: *276 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:37:19 [info] 885#885: *288 client 151.217.75.156 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 19:40:22 [info] 885#885: *311 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:42:05 [info] 885#885: *341 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:42:05 [info] 885#885: *339 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:42:05 [info] 885#885: *332 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:42:05 [info] 885#885: *335 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 19:44:52 [info] 885#885: *348 client 47.62.114.44 closed keepalive connection (104: Connection reset by peer)
2019/08/23 20:51:07 [info] 885#885: *352 client 84.41.107.234 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 21:23:54 [info] 885#885: *354 client 181.118.94.19 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 22:02:16 [info] 885#885: *356 client 138.122.20.90 closed keepalive connection
2019/08/23 22:47:07 [info] 885#885: *358 client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 61.219.11.153, server: , request: ""
2019/08/23 22:56:28 [info] 885#885: *359 client 150.242.255.221 closed keepalive connection
```

I suspect there's some problem with my nginx configuration, but I don't know what it is.

I guess the production / debug android versions are different in someway, which would explain why the request works on my device when installed from android studio, but not from the play store. I don't know what that difference is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Android now defaults to only allowing requests over HTTPS. My request was sent over HTTP. When this happens, the request fails silently.

To allow HTTP requests add the following to `application` your manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`):
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Alternatively, you can make the request over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with signed Apk

Delete your android/build folder, ./gradle file

Generate a debug Apk

Then generate signed Apk

Comment: This was not the issue, but is a reasonable thing for people to try who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be a proguard issue. It might work on 32 bit and fail on 64 bit or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
project      
│
└───android
   │
   └───app
       │  
       │____src
             |
             |___main
                 |___ AndroidManifest.xml
```

Inside <application tag add this line like this

```
<application

android:usesCleartextTraffic=”true” >
```

Simple and easy!